# Intel 8086, a few little things

Tags: assembly, encoding, x86-16

Would the encoding for the 8086 instruction of `MOV AL,4` be `c604`?

Also, how would I encode `MOV AX, DS:5678h` and `SUB BX,[Di+6]`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is 16-bit assembly, right?

Comment: Ok, I'm working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MOV AL,4` is encoded to `B004`.

`MOV AX, DS:5678h` is an `invalid combination of opcode and operands`. This will not compile.

`SUB BX, [DI+6]` is encoded to `2B5D06`.

---

For those interested, this is how to decode compiled 16-bit assembler.

... this may be a good wiki.

Firstly: This was done on Mac OS X, but any Linux distribution can use the tools described.

In x86 (8086) assembler language, as well as many other assembly languages, the assembler compiles (barely) human-readable mnemonics to bytecode. Each mnemonic converts to a specific bytecode. For example:

`XOR AX, AX` encodes to `31C0`.

To decode machine-language, you will need your favorite text editor, NASM (Netwide Assembler), and a hex editor.

Step 1: Enter your mnemonic to decode in your text editor, with the [BITS 16] instruction first. Save.

[image: step1]

Step 2: Compile with the command `nasm <your file> -f bin -o <output file>`

[image: step2]

Step 3: Open the output file with the hex editor.

[image: step3]

Step 4: The bytes shown will be the decoded mnemonic.

---

Here is how to decompile bytecode to NASM-syntax mnemonics. This is the reverse of the steps described above.

NASM comes with the tool `ndisasm`- or the Netwide Disassembler. This program will disassemble bytecode back into original instructions.

You will need the NASM set of tools, and, if you want, a hex editor.

Step 1: Get your bytecode file. This should be compiled assembler language. C/C++ code, or any other machine-language file may include a header before the actual machine code.

If you want, you can examine/edit your bytecode file with a hex editor.

[image: step4]

Step 2: Run this command: `ndisasm -b 16 <bytecode file>`. The line(s) shown on the right of the terminal are the mnemonic(s) from the byte code.

[image: step1-2]

If the bytecode is not valid, sometimes `ndisasm` will say that certain bytes are `db` mnemonics- these means `define byte`. In other words, this is a filler byte, and `ndisasm` could not find a valid mnemonic for it.

[image: step2-2]

Also, keep in mind that when using `ndisasm`, and any other decompiler or disassembler, the decompiler/disassembler will not retrieve comments or blank space.

Comment: Pictures will be added.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, do you know of any quick way to do the reverse? So taking B004 and finding out what it is?

Comment: mov ax, ds:5678h depending on the particular assembly syntax may be encoded as A1 78 56 (mov ax, [ds:5678h] in FASM syntax).

Comment: It's finished. user77708, the reverse is explained above. Good luck with your project!